# Data corruption to protect the encryption?

Tags: encryption

On [KeePass help center](https://keepass.info/help/base/repair.html) it's stated that:

> ... if the header of the database (first few bytes) is corrupted, you're out of luck, too: the repair functionality won't be able to restore any entries (because the header contains information required to decrypt the database).

I wonder if header corruption (or maybe other type of small damage) can make it impossible (even if you have the password) to decrypt any data from encrypted files, like KeePass databases, 7z archives, VeraCrypt containers....?

Comment: Depending on what's in the header, yes. For example, if you store the encryption key for the file in the header, you won't be able to decrypt the header to read the key. So, you can think of it like protection from tampering anywhere else in the file.

Comment: OTOH, if it just contains an altered version byte, and you can restore said byte to its original value then everything could work again. As samuel-lucas6 said, it depends.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 but as far as in know, no one of the mentioned programs stores the encryption key. It's actually derived from the password.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes my intention is to delete about 1KB (or 10KB if it's necessary), to make sure that even a partial data decryption becomes impossible (assuming the attacker gets the password, or quantum computers become fast enough to break AES-256 encryption). Before that, i will create a small par2 file for the encrypted file, and i will keep it in a different location. This way, i can fix the corruption when it's needed. But, I'm not sure if such intentional damage is good enough to reach my goal.

Comment: @oqdn I'm pretty sure VeraCrypt derives a header key to encrypt a key stored in the header, among other things. I'm not sure what the format of KeePass is, but it's common practice to wrap a key. Cryptomator is another example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bapcap's answer, password based encryption systems (KeePassXC, Veracrypt, etc) operate differently than pure key-based encryption systems (age in key mode, BitLocker with a TPM, etc).

Password-based encryption systems need to be able to allow the user to change their password, without having to re-encrypt all the encrypted data. They do this by having two encryption keys.

First, a "Key Encryption Key" (KEK) is derived from the user's passphrase, a salt, and some difficulty parameters using a "password hashing function" such as Argon2 or bcrypt. Then a random "Data Encryption Key" (DEK) is generated. The data is encrypted using the DEK, and then the DEK is encrypted with the KEK. The encrypted DEK, the salt, and the difficulty parameters are stored in the "header" of the encrypted file data file.

To decrypt the data, the header is read, the user's password is hashed (with the salt & using the parameters) to derived the KEK, and the DEK is decrypted. Then the file is decrypted with the DEK.

To change the user's password, the KEK is derived just like when decrypting the file, and the DEK is decrypted. Then a new KEK is created with a new salt & parameters, the DEK is encrypted with the new KEK, and the encrypted DEK, new salt, and parameters are stored in the header.

Answer (score 0):

In the header for most encryption algorithms, the header is not supposed to be the key itself, that would be foolishly insecure. The Header simply notifies the program that this is a drive that has been encrypted with it. By wiping the header, you remove it's ability to sense that it was encrypted, thus making it impossible to tell whether its just garbage or obfuscated data.

On Veracrypt for example, the header is the ASCII string "VERA". If the first four bytes of the decryption has this string, decryption for the rest of the bytes and bits is considered succesful and truthful to the original data. Wiping this makes it impossible to tell. This header is encrypted, so it is already obfuscated.

> Decryption is considered successful if the first 4 bytes of the decrypted data contain the ASCII string “VERA”, and if the CRC-32 checksum of the last 256 bytes of the decrypted data (volume header) matches the value located at byte #8 of the decrypted data (this value is unknown to an adversary because it is encrypted. [Veracrypt Encryption Scheme](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Encryption%20Scheme.html)

Wiping this would remove the ability for any programs to tell if encryption took place. So the answer to this is "kind of." Theoretically all one needs to do is just do the decryption without using the header for reference. The adversary would not know the algorithm (AES, Serpent, Twofish, et cetera) so brute forcing each algorithm would be required. They would not know whether or not the data was corrupted after "decryption."

It makes things a lot harder for the adversary, but not theoretically impossible. On practical human lifespans, yes.